# creating metapackage

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic, metapackage

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is there any good reference for creating metapackage?
Or
Is there any command like catkin_create_pkg for creating normal package?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/322340/creating-metapackage/) by [JMM](https://answers.ros.org/users/39192/jmm/) on ROS Answers with karma: 51 on 2019-05-02

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on 2019-05-02**:
Is http://wiki.ros.org/catkin/package.xml#Metapackages enough?

As it states:

> A metapackage is a normal package...

it is sufficient to use `catkin_create_pkg <WHATEVER>`, add the mentioned tag in the `package.xml`, add the respective dependencies and replace the `CMakeLists.txt` with the boilerplate one. Note that this needs to be exact that (whitespace!) except for the package name.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-05-02**:
Might be a nice PR to extend `catkin_create_pkg` so it can generate metapackages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Actually, @gvdhoorn's recommendation is already implemented.
So now posting as answer:

```
catkin_create_pkg <MY_META_PACKAGE> --meta
```

will do what you want.
You still have to add the dependencies to the package.xml, though. But this is actually trivial...

---

Originally posted by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) with karma: 12390 on 2019-05-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 9

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-05-03**:
Yes, indeed. Not sure how I missed that in the `--help` of `catkin_create_pkg`:

```
optional arguments:
  --meta                Creates meta-package files
```

**Comment by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on 2019-05-03**:
I'm stumped how I missed that as well. This feature is actually [four years old](https://github.com/ros-infrastructure/catkin_pkg/pull/116) and I've been copying around files to achieve this :-D

**Comment by [JMM](https://answers.ros.org/users/39192/jmm/) on 2019-05-07**:
thanks guys